# Division Formula Issue in rtf Template - XML Publisher

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a sum of a column "bucket_3" in a cell(suppose cell A) and and column "EXPOSURE" in another cell(suppose cell B).
I am trying to calculate A divide by B i.e A/B using this code:

```
<?if:sum(EXPOSURE)=0 ?>
<?xdoxslt:div(sum(BUCKET_3),sum(EXPOSURE))?>
<?else?>
<?end if?> this gives no result.
```

when i tried just
`<?xdoxslt:div(sum(BUCKET_3),sum(EXPOSURE))?>` this gives 0 as a result.

Kindly Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following xdofx function. This should work-

```
<?xdofx: sum(BUCKET_3) div sum(EXPOSURE)?>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e13881/T527073T558233.htm